# New Office 365 EWS OAuth2 scope related bug "The item is opened in read-only mode"?

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365api, outlook-restapi

Hope Office 365 team gets this on their radar,

We provide a sync service for our clients which includes deletion syncing also. About a week ago Office 365 EWS API started rejecting item deletions for users that had been syncing for months without any problems (OAuth2 based connections):

> ErrorAccessDenied: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The item is opened in read-only mode.

Something has definitely changed in the Office 365 EWS behavior. I have a feeling Microsoft has introduced an OAuth2 scope handling bug recently for EWS that somehow excluded the "delete item" permission.

Our OAuth2 access tokens always had the EWS.AccessAsUser.All scope which is supposed to be giving the read/write/delete permissions.

Thoughts?

Comment: You're not talking to the Office 365 team here. This is a completely unaffiliated question and answer site.

Comment: The Office 365 team asks their developers to ask questions here as they're monitoring relevant tags so this questions is for them. And Google has been asking the developers the same. Their engineers are actually on this site, providing support.

Answer (score 1):

Alexey is right. There was a regression in calendar sharing sync code that caused this problem with removing a cancelled occurrence from a recurring meeting. The change is being backed out starting 1800 UTC on 1/3/2019, and is expected to be fully backed out within 3 days.